# How to check string is present or not using grep in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to find whether a value is present in a string or not using grep in if condition. I tried few code but that was incorrect

This is for windows running Perl.

```
$string ="This is a test string";
$val ="test";
if( grep /$val/i, $string)
print "found";
else
print "not found";
```

I expect the output to be found

Comment: I need to find it using grep not with index

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use `grep` for that purpose?

Comment: @GMB because I need to check that string with multiple values. I'll make it simple, Suppose im having an array @val=("demo","test","gone"); . So I need to check any of these values are present in the string and also need to know which value it is matched to.

Answer (score 1):

[grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) is useful when filtering a list. String is not a list in Perl, you should just just the match or [index](http://p3rl.org/index).

```
if (-1 != index $string, $val) {
```

or

```
if ($string =~ /$val/i) {
```

Your syntax is wrong. When using `if` with `else`, curly brackets aren't optional.

```
if (grep /$val/i, $string) {
    print "found";
} else {
    print "not found";
}
```

Comment: What if I have multiple string values to match.For example, $val is an array.How to check whether anyone of the array value matches the string

Comment: @Sahal, That's where grep is useful.

Comment: @ikegami Can you show some demo code for that?

Comment: @Sahal, As per [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), one of the usage is `grep EXPR, LIST`, and "`LIST`" means an "expression that returns zero or more scalars in list context". `@a` is such an expression.